# Multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker when adding to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of `IEntityChangeTracker` when I do:

```
context.Orders.Add(order);
```

I'm trying to add an order to the database. I can't see where I'm using multiple instances, something to do with the way I'm getting the user/customer?

Thanks

```
// get user
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = userManager.FindById(userId);

Models.Customer customer = user as Models.Customer;

// create order
Order order = new Order();
order.CustomerId = userId;
order.Customer = customer;
order.OrderStatus = OrderStatus.New;
order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
order.OrderLines = (List<OrderLine>)Session["basket"];
order.IsPaid = false;

// get orderLines from session basket
List<OrderLine> basket = (List<OrderLine>)Session["basket"];

// calculate order total
order.OrderTotal = (from data in basket select data.Product.Price * data.Quantity).Sum();

// save to database
context.Orders.Add(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Do you have a separate Identity-related DbContext and application-specific DbContext? It looks like you get the user from the former, then try to attach it to your Order entity tracked by the latter.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks, I replaced the way i was getting the user with: string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); var user = context.Users.Find(userId);

Answer (score 0):

fixed by replacing:

```
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var user = userManager.FindById(userId);
```

with:

```
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = context.Users.Find(userId);
```